# Python - creating aws lambda deployment package

Tags: python, boto, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to script updating code for my AWS Lambda using a Fabric task. Boto3 api expects a byte array of base-64 encoded zip file.

What would be the simplest way to create it assuming I have the source code files as the input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the current boto3, don't unzip it, don't base64 encode it.
You can do it with an open and a read like this:

```
import boto3
c = boto3.client('lambda')
c.create_function({
    'FunctionName': 'your_function',
    'Handler': 'your_handler',
    'Runtime': 'python3.6',
    'Code': {'ZipFile': open('./deploy.zip', 'rb').read()}
})
```

I use the zip file above for getting started quickly. You can also upload the deploy.zip to a S3 bucket and pass the bucket + key as strings in the 'Code' dict as 'S3Bucket' and 'S3Key'.

Comment: FYI: I'm still using the above code with boto3 1.9.

Comment: I used the same code, However I am getting error that No such directory

Answer (score 1):

Actually boto3 documentation is out of date, you should pass the bytes directly:

https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/201

As to the zip file this should point you in the right direction:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html
- http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Python-UnZipped/
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray

Comment: Yes, I've looked at them. They don't answer my question though. As I've mentioned I'd like to use boto create_function method that accepts a byte array of base-64 encoded zip file.

Comment: actually IIUC  you can pass the bytes directly, did you tried that?https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/201

Comment: Thats useful! So the remaining part is how to zip file and then get the bytes out of it in elegant way? Ideally I was thinking about doing it all in memory without intermediary files.

Comment: I edited the answer so it could provide the pointers necessary for you and for future reference.

Comment: There is code in kappa that does this.  Perhaps it would be useful.  Specifically, checkout: https://github.com/garnaat/kappa/blob/develop/kappa/function.py#L121

Comment: Both kappa and @rsFF examples do zipping via intermediary file. I guess that means this is the only choice then?