# boto3 Lambda create_function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a zip file containing my lambda handler, but I don't know how to specify it as part of the Code parameter. The documentation says to use a ZipFile entry in the Code dictionary parameter, but how am I supposed to convert the zip file I have into "the base64 encoded contents"?

Here is the link to the doc

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - creating aws lambda deployment package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022161/python-creating-aws-lambda-deployment-package)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to encode it yourself, boto3 handles it for you.

> ZipFile (bytes) --
>   The base64-encoded contents of the deployment package. **AWS SDK and AWS CLI clients handle the encoding for you.**

Check out some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022161/python-creating-aws-lambda-deployment-package).